# Have Nagios execute a command when it detects a down host

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I would like Nagios to execute a Bash command/script when it detects a host down or up. This would allow me to react to down hosts to some degree which would be very interesting.

How would I do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Event handlers are your friends: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html.

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 3):

into your commands file add the command you need

```
define command{
# try this before

command_name my_restart
command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/my_restart.sh $HOSTADDRESS$ $SERVICESTATE$ $SERVICESTATETYPE$ $SERVICEATTEMPT$
}
```

into your service defination

```
define service{
 .....
event_handler           my_restart
 ....
```

}

the arguments that you receive into your script are the ones defined into the command file,
you can see them as well by doing echo $@ into your script - is important to know the host address in case that you will call against a remote host and the service state (you take different actions on CRITICAL, OK or WARNING)

i suggest you have some logging into your script at least at the beginning.

Comment: Note that if it's a HOST check the states are UP/DOWN/UNREACHABLE not CRITICAL/WARNING/OK/UNKNOWN. Important distinction!